# org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property. Bean property is not readable or has an invalid getter method

Tags: java, forms, data-binding, playframework-2.2

I struggle with this errors:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'customer' of bean class [common.controllers.Index$Login]: Bean property 'customer' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'customer' does not have a corresponding accessor for data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
```

I can't figure out when I did make code change, that causes this error.
Few days ago it just worked.

Here is full stack trace:

```
ERROR | 2015-07-23 15:52:37 | Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'customer' does not have a corresponding accessor for data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
ERROR | 2015-07-23 15:52:37 | 

! @6mpn2f397 - Internal server error, for (POST) [/] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'customer' does not have a corresponding accessor for data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:268) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:268) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:268) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$$anon$1.execute(Execution.scala:43) [play-iteratees_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'customer' does not have a corresponding accessor for data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
        at play.data.Form.bind(Form.java:344) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.data.Form.bindFromRequest(Form.java:216) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at common.controllers.Index.authenticate(Index.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(routes_routing.scala:559) ~[na:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(routes_routing.scala:559) ~[na:na]
        at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$7$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:183) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:377) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:56) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.GlobalSettings$1.call(GlobalSettings.java:64) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at common.actions.IpValidateAction$AuthenticatedAction.call(IpValidateAction.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction$1.apply(TransactionalAction.java:20) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction$1.apply(TransactionalAction.java:18) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransactionAsync(JPA.java:177) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.call(TransactionalAction.java:15) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'customer' of bean class [common.controllers.Index$Login]: Bean property 'customer' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:707) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:699) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99) ~[spring-context.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.rejectValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:105) ~[spring-context.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at play.data.Form.bind(Form.java:338) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
ERROR | 2015-07-23 15:52:37 | REGUEST: POST / GENERATED ERROR: @6mpn2f397: Execution exception in /home/korbeldaniel/git/SVP2/SVP2/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/routes_routing.scala:559
App mode 1: centralMode
```

Generally it is problem with binding data from serialized html form to java object of class `Form<>`

Here is my login class:

```
    public static class Login {

        /** The customer. */
        @ManyToOne
        @Constraints.Required
        public Customer customer;

        /** The password. */
        public String password;

        public String loginType;

        public Login() {
            super();
        }

        public Login(Customer customer) {
            super();
            this.customer = customer;
        }
        public Login(Customer customer, String password, String loginType) {
            super();
            this.customer = customer;
            this.password = password;
            this.loginType = loginType;
        }
}
```

Here is my Customer class:

```
public class Customer {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) public Long id;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new customer.
     */
    public Customer() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new customer.
     *
     * @param new_id the new_id
     */
    public Customer(Long new_id) {
        super();
        id = new_id;
    }
}
```

I don't paste form view class, cause this error occur while binding each form that contain customer class/parameter.

Here is binding code when the error occur:

```
Form<Login> filledLoginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
```

I use playframeworks form class for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the javabean specification with your Login class.  You can leave the customer member of Login public, but you'll have to wrap it in a getter/setter:

```
public Customer getCustomer() {

 return this.customer();

}

public void setCustomer(Customer c) {

 this.customer = c;

}
```

You say play should be generating those getters/setters for you at compile time, but doesn't seem to be. My understanding is that It only does this only for entity/model classes and I don't see an JPA @Entity annotation on Login.  Also having Login be a static class seems strange to me.

Comment: I assume that in getter You mean this code: `return this.customer;`? In a moment I will test Your suggestion, but I don't have getters and  setter in my bean classes,  cause I use playFramework, which is should generate them automatically.

Comment: It works. Thanks. It is strange cause playframework should generate getters and setters on compilation time as I know. But now I am not sure why he didn't.

Comment: Agreed, I was just reading the stack trace. Why is your Login class static? And is it marked with an Entity annotation?